# HTML5 video streaming issue

Tags: html, streaming

I know this kind of problem was already mentioned, but, I have to play some videos who are encoded in MP4 (h264 / AAC). Some of them are 2 hours long, sometimes more.

The problem is that they don't start quickly, because I need to download a random amount of data to be able to play the video : the browser doesn't load the entire file, but 5/6MB, which is a problem for the lowest connexions.

I tried the FFMpeg option -movflags +faststart but it changes nothing.
I tried the qt-faststart tool, it says "last atom in file was not a moov atom".
The server seems to be configurated to allow partial requests (Accept-Ranges:bytes in Response Headers).

Did I tried everything? Is there something more I can do?

Thanks !
Romain

Comment: Create a stream with a lower bitrate?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. The size of videos is already very low : 200Mo for 1hour. I can't reduce the quality more because there is some important details (it's RichMedia files with synchronized Powerpoints).

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into adaptive streaming. Either HLS or DASH format would solve your problem. It does entail to review your media delivery architecture and your video player.

Example here: https://www.keycdn.com/support/how-to-convert-mp4-to-hls/

Players like JW Player can read both format on most platforms.